# Exercise 23 from chapter 4 (“Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction”) of Stein & Shakarchi's “Real Analysis”

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider exercise 23 from chapter 4 ("Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction") of [1] (p. 198). Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

> Suppose $\{T_k\}$ is a collection of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with $\|T_k\|\leq1$ for all $k$. Suppose also that
>   $$
> T_kT_j^* = T_k^*T_j = 0\hspace{1cm}\mbox{for all } k \neq j.
> $$
>   Let $S_N = \sum_{k = -N}^N T_k$.
>
> Show that $S_N(f)$ converges as $N \rightarrow \infty$, for every $f \in \mathcal{H}$. If $T(f)$ denotes the limit, prove that $\|T\| \leq 1$.
>
> [Hint: Consider first the case when only finitely many of the $T_k$ are non-zero, and note that the ranges of the $T_k$ are mutually orthogonal.]

Note: I realize why - as the hint suggests - the ranges of the $T_k$'s are mutually orthogonal. Indeed, let $k, j \in \mathbb{Z}$ be distinct, and let $h_k, h_j \in \mathcal{H}$. Then
$$
\left<T_j h_j, T_k h_k\right> = \left<T_k^* T_j h_j, h_k\right> = \left<0, h_k\right> = 0
$$

---

***References***

[1] Stein, Elias M. and Shakarchi, Rami. Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces. Princeton University Press (2005)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_{k}$ be the orthogonal projection onto the closure of the range of $T_{k}$. Then $P_{k}P_{k'}=P_{k'}P_{k}=0$ for $k\ne k'$ because $(T_{k}x,T_{k'}y)=(T_{k'}^{\star}T_{k}x,y)=0$ for all $x,y \in H$. Similarly, if $Q_{k}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closure of the range of $T_{k}^{\star}$, then $Q_{k}Q_{k'}=0$ for $k\ne k'$. Furthermore,
$$
       (T_{k}x,y)=(T_{k}x,P_{k}y)=(x,T_{k}^{\star}P_{k}y)=(Q_{k}x,T_{k}^{\star}P_{k}y)=
         (T_{k}Q_{k}x,P_{k}y).
$$
If $F$ is any finite subset of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\|T\| \le 1$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and Bessel's inequality together yield
$$
\begin{align}
    |\sum_{k\in F}(T_{k}x,y)| & \le \sum_{k\in F}|(T_{k}Q_{k}x,P_{k}y)| \\
           & \le \sum_{k\in F}\|T_{k}Q_{k}x\|\|P_{k}y\| \\
           & \le \sum_{k\in F}\|Q_{k}x\|\|P_{k}y\| \\
           & \le \left(\sum_{k\in F}\|Q_{k}x\|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k\in F}\|P_{k}y\|^{2}\right)^{1/2} \\
           & \le \|x\|\|y\|.
\end{align}
$$
It follows that, regardless of the finite subset $F$, one has the inequality
$$
              \|\sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x\| \le \|x\|,\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{H}.
$$
Because $\{ T_{k}x\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a mutually orthogonal set of vectors, then
$$
          \sum_{k\in F}\|T_{k}x\|^{2} = \|\sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x\|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\|T_{k}x\|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$. Because $s_{N}=\sum_{k=-N}^{N}\|T_{k}x\|^{2}<\infty$ is a convergent sequence, then it is a Cauchy sequence. So, $\sum_{k=-N}^{N}T_{k}x$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ because, for $0 < N < M$,
$$
\begin{align}
           \|\sum_{k=-M}^{M}T_{k}x-\sum_{k=-N}^{N}T_{k}x\|^{2}& =\sum_{N < |k| \le M}\|T_{k}x\|^{2} \\
             & =\sum_{k=-M}^{M}\|T_{k}x\|^{2}-\sum_{k=-N}^{N}\|T_{k}x\|^{2}.
\end{align}
$$
Knowing that $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space allows one to conclude that
$$
             Tx = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=-N}^{N}T_{k}x
$$
exists for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$. Furthermore, by what was shown, $\|Tx\|\le \|x\|$ because the same is true for all finite sums $\sum_{k=-N}^{N}T_{k}x$.

Comment: Thank you. There's just one point I don't understand: the justification for the inequality $\left(\sum_{k\in F}\|Q_{k}x\|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k\in F}\|P_{k}y\|^{2}\right)^{1/2} \le \|x\|\|y\|$. I presume it is justified by some version of Bessel's inequality, but the only version I am familiar with is: "If $(e_1, e_2, \dots)$ is an orthogonal basis, then, for all $x$, $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty |\left<x,e_i\right>|^2\leq\|x\|^2$."

Comment: @EvanAad : That's basically it, except that Bessel's inequality does not assume a full basis, but only an orthonormal set. Parseval's equality is when you have a full basis. For a fixed $x$, all of the non-zero $Q_{k}x$ give an orthonormal set $e_{n}=\|Q_{n}x\|^{-1}Q_{n}x$, with $(x,e_{n})=(x,Q_{n}x)/\|Q_{n}x\|=(Q_{n}x,Q_{n}x)/\|Q_{n}x\|=\|Q_{n}x\|$. So $\sum_{k\in K}|(x,e_{k})|^{2}=\sum_{k\in F}\|Q_{k}x\|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. If the other responder answers my question, I will mark his post as THE answer, because he posted 2 hour before you. By the way, in paragraph 1 I think "Let $P_{k}$ be the orthogonal projection onto the range of $T_{k}$." should be replaced by "... onto the closure of the range of $T_{k}$", because is a projection onto a non-closed subspace even defined? Also, "if $Q_{k}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $T_{k}$" should be "... onto the range of $T_{k}^{\star}$", (or, rather, "... onto the closure of the range of $T_{k}^{\star}$"), or else $Q_k=P_k$ .

Comment: @EvanAad : Yes, you are correct. I'll fix that.

Comment: @EvanAad : It's fine if you mark the other as a solution. I just wanted to post to show you how to do it using the given hint of looking at a finite number first.

Answer (score 2):

First observation: For all $u,v\in\mathcal H$ and $j\ne k$
$$
\langle T_ju,T_k v\rangle=\langle T_j^*u,T_k^* v\rangle=0.
$$
Thus the linear subspaces $T_j^*\mathcal H$, $j\in\mathbb Z$, are perpendicular to each other, and so are their closures. Set 
$$
Y=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb Z}\overline{T_j^*\mathcal H}.
$$ 
This infinite direct sum contains elements of the form $t=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}t_j$, where 
$\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\|t_j\|^2<\infty$, and hence $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$.

Then $\mathcal H=Y\oplus Y^\perp$, and thus every $h\in \mathcal H$ can be writen (uniquely) as
$$
h=z+\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}t_j, \quad z\in Y^\perp,\,t_j\in\overline{T_j^*\mathcal H},\qquad(\star)
$$
and clearly
$$
\|h\|^2=\|z\|^2+\sum_{j\in\mathcal Z}\|t_j\|^2. \qquad (\star\star)
$$
Now, if $z\in Y^\perp$, then $\langle z,T_j^*u\rangle=0$, for all $u\in\mathcal H$, and 
thus  $\langle T_jz,u\rangle=0$, for all $u\in\mathcal H$, which means that $T_jz=0$. Also,
if $t_j\in \overline{T_j^*\mathcal H}$, then clearly $T_kt_j=0$, for all $k\ne j$.

Hence, 
using representation $(\star)$ we have
$$
S_Nh=\sum_{|j|\le N}T_j\Big(z+\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}t_k\Big)=\sum_{|j|\le N}T_jt_j.
$$
In particular,
$$
\|S_Mh-S_Nh\|^2=\sum_{N<|j|\le M}\|T_jt_j\|^2\le \sum_{N<|j|\le M}\|t_j\|^2\to 0,
$$
as $M,N\to\infty$, since the series $(\star\star)$ converges. Thus 
$$
Th=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_Nh,
$$
is well-defined, and
$$
\|Th\|^2=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} \|T_jt_j\|^2\le \sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} \|t_j\|^2\le \|h\|^2,
$$
and hence $\|T\|\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you. There is one point I don't understand: "Set $Y=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb Z}\overline{T_j^*\mathcal H}.$" Why is this direct sum well-defined? Finite direct sums of orthogonal, closed subspaces are well-defined, but why are infinite direct sums of such subspaces well-defined?