# bounded operators $\{T_k\}$ and convergence of $S_N(f)$ where $S_N = \sum_{k=-N}^{N}T_k$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following exercise $23$ of chapter $4$ of Stein's Real Analysis.

> **Exercise 23**
>
> Suppose $\{T_k\}$ is a collection of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with $\|T_k\|\leq1$ for all $k$. Suppose also that
> $$
> T_kT_j^* = T_k^*T_j = 0\hspace{1cm}\mbox{for all } k \neq j.
> $$
> Let $S_N = \sum_{k = -N}^N T_k$.
>
> Show that $S_N(f)$ converges as $N \rightarrow \infty$, for every $f \in \mathcal{H}$. If $T(f)$ denotes the limit, prove that $\|T\| \leq 1$.
>
> [Hint: Consider first the case when only finitely many of the $T_k$ are non-zero, and note that the ranges of the $T_k$ are mutually orthogonal.]

Now, I'm studying [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/937294/1118138) to understand the exercise, and there are some points that I can't fully understand.

The first point is the following sentence;

> It follows that, regardless of the finite subset $F$, one has the inequality
> $$\Vert \sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x\Vert \le \Vert x\Vert ,\qquad x \in \mathcal{H}.$$

I've tried to connect this with the previous inequality $|\sum_{k\in F}(T_{k}x,y)| \le \Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert$, but I couldn't find the relationship btw these. Applying $y = x$ doesn't lead to any useful result.

The second is the following sentence

> Because $s_{N}=\sum_{k=-N}^{N}\|T_{k}x\|^{2}<\infty$ is a convergent sequence,

Right before this sentence, this proved the following statement $\sum_{k\in F}\Vert T_{k}x\Vert ^{2} = \Vert \sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x\Vert ^{2} \le \Vert x\Vert ^{2}$. However, $\Vert x \Vert$ is not always finite, so $\sum_{k\in F}\Vert T_{k}x\Vert ^{2}$ is not always finite. This is what I've understood. Then, why $s_N$ is convergent??

Finally, I want to make this statement more clearly.

> Furthermore, by what was shown, $\Vert Tx\Vert \le \Vert x\Vert$

Assuming the all of the previous statements are correct, $\Vert \sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x\Vert ^{2} \le \Vert x\Vert ^{2}$ holds for all $F \subset \mathbb N$. Then, $\Vert \sum_{k =  -N}^N T_{k}x\Vert ^{2} \le \Vert x\Vert ^{2}$ holds for all $N \in \mathbb N$. So, $\lim_{N\to \infty} \Vert \sum_{k =  -N}^N T_{k}x\Vert \le \Vert x\Vert$. This is what I've understood. Then, how could I extend to the result that we want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v= \sum_{k\in F}T_{k}x$.  if $v=0$ it is trivial that $\|v\|\le\|x\|$.  If $v\ne 0$, let $y=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$.  Then $\|y\| = 1$ and
$$|\langle v, y\rangle| \le \|x\| \|y\| = \|x\|$$
but
$$|\langle v, y\rangle| = |\langle v, \frac{v}{\|v\|}\rangle| = \frac{\|v\|^2}{\|v\|} = \|v\|$$
So $\|v\|\le \|x\|$.

Second question - $\|x\|$ is always finite because $x$ is a assumed to be a member of $\mathcal{H}$.

Third question - Let $v_N = \sum_{k=-N}^N T_{k}x$ and $v = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} v_N$.  For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $m$ such that $\|v - v_k\| \le \varepsilon$ for all $k > m$.  But $\|v_k\| \le \|x\|$ for all $k>m$, so by the triangle inequality $\|v\| \le \|x\| + \varepsilon$.  Since $\varepsilon$ was any positive number it follows that $\|v\|\le \|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to ask one more question (about 2nd one). While reading the Stein's textbook, I couldn't find that $f \in \mathcal H$ has a finite norm. Is this just a simple definition? or a proposition induced from other properties such as Bessel's inequality?

Comment: The definition of of Hilbert space is that the inner-product is finite-valued, and the norm of $f$ is just $\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$ so it has a finite value.